# Dockerfile ENV backtick interpolation

Tags: docker, environment-variables, dockerfile

How can I use bash's backtick interpolation in a Dockerfile's ENV command?

Dockerfile:

> FROM node
>
> RUN npm i -g yarn
>
> ENV PATH="$PATH:`yarn global bin`"

The problem is that in bash, `yarn global bin` gets interpolated to an actual string (i.e. /usr/local/bin) but in Dockerfile, a backtick is an escape character.

Comment: You can't, not really.  The 'ENV' command gets executed on the build machine, not inside the container, so the backticks would be meaningless (or worse, give the value from the host machine).  You could use a 'RUN' command to save the value to a file or something... however, one reason to use Docker instead of other tools is that it is deterministic... you already know what the output of that command is going to be, so why not just put that value there?

Comment: @PaulBecotte this is what I'm doing now. But if a new version of yarn changed the \`global bin folder\` , then the hard coded path will be wrong in the future.